# mongoid cannot connect to remote server, no auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have a `mongod` running at my network's internal subnet of `10.1.150.24` and my `mogoid.yml` has these lines:

```
  hosts:
    - 10.1.150.24:27017
```

MongoDB is running without authentication on the remote server.
On the remote server a rails app with `- localhost:27017` connects without issues. The `mongod.conf` has

```
net:
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

set and should accept connections on all interfaces.

I can see the connection error when I am in `rails c` on my local and try to create an object or even retrieve one.

`Foo.create(...)` failes like this:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb:35:in `+'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb:35:in `digest'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb:47:in `build_auth_command'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb:25:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/authenticatable.rb:71:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/authenticatable.rb:71:in `login'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/authenticatable.rb:28:in `block in apply_credentials'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/authenticatable.rb:26:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/authenticatable.rb:26:in `apply_credentials'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/node.rb:180:in `block in ensure_connected'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/node.rb:115:in `block in connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/connection_pool-2.1.1/lib/connection_pool.rb:62:in `with'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/node.rb:114:in `connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/node.rb:178:in `ensure_connected'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/node.rb:589:in `block in flush'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/moped-2.0.3/lib/moped/node.rb:617:in `block in logging'
... 33 levels...
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /home/mwerner/workspace/pricing/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Given the number of `authentication` errors with `moped` I am confused since there is no authentication on the mongo instance.

EDIT: I also tried ssh tunneling the 27017 port to my local and setting localhost in monogoid.yml No luck

Answer (score 0):

running `sudo gem pristine --all` and killing the spring process fixed the issue. I can now connect to the remote server.